# Display thank you message and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, onclick, href, alert, form-submit

Currently, I managed to create alert pop-up "Thanks" after on-click event.
It works for 1 second and redirect to https://www.w3schools.com.

How to create not pop-up alert, but a kind of temporary blank page with "Thanks" for 3-4 seconds in the middle?

After this I want to be redirected to https://www.w3schools.com.

```js
function two() {
  alert('Thanks');
  window.location.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="two();" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a splash page that gets displayed above the current content and then use a timeout to redirect the user.

**Edit:** Moved the text to the CSS rule. If you do not want this, add the text inside the `<div class="thanks">` tag and remove the `:after` CSS rule.

```js
function redirect() {
  document.querySelector('.thanks').classList.remove('thanks-hidden');
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com/';
  }, 3000); // Wait 3 seconds and then redirect.
}
```

```css
.thanks {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.thanks:after {
  content: "Thanks";
}

.thanks-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="redirect()" value="Submit">
<div class="thanks thanks-hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mr. Polywhirl! Can I increase your rating somehow?

Comment: @VolodyaZhyla you valued accept my response, if this helped you achieve your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout

```
function two() {
  alert('Thanks');
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com';
  }, 4000 /* ms to delay for*/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to set a timer for a specific function. You can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to clear the content of the body.

```js
function two() {
  alert('Thanks');
  document.body.innerHTML = '';
  setTimeout(() => {
window.location.href = 'https://www.w3schools.com';
},4000);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="two();" value="Submit">
```